# laravel verify shopify webhook

Tags: laravel, shopify, sha256, webhooks, verify

How can I verify my shopify webhooks in laravel?
Currently I'm doing the following:

```
//Validate secret 
    if ( Request::header( 'X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256' ) ) {
        $hmac_header = Request::header( 'X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256' );
        $data = Request::json();
        $calculated_hmac = base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha256', $data, Config::get( 'constants.SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET' ), true ) );
        if ( $hmac_header != $calculated_hmac ) {
            return Response::json( array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => "invalid secret" ),
                403 );
        }
    }else {
        return Response::json( array(
                'error' => true,
                'message' => "no secret" ),
            403 );
    }
```

But it fails with the following message:

```
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'hash_hmac() exp...', '/Users/JS/Sites...', 58, Array)
#1 /Users/JS/Sites/xxx/api/app/controllers/CustomerController.php(58): hash_hmac('sha256', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag), 'xxxxxxxxxx...', true)
```

I suspect it has sth to do with the way I get the request data:

```
$data = Request::json();
```

Does anyone have a solution? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the example given in the Shopify docs: https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks#verify-webhook

Replace

```
$data = Request::json();
```

with

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You can still use `Request::json()` elsewhere to get a ParameterBag for processing data from the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my handler, works good:

```
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, [SECRET], true));
            if (!$hmac_header =  $request->header('X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256') or 
    $hmac_header != $calculated_hmac or $request->email == 'jon@doe.ca') {

                return Response::json(['error' => true], 403);
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
```

note that:

`$request->email == 'jon@doe.ca'` for case if there is not received test hooks for some reason
`[SECRET]` is the code from the store notifications settings under the webhook callback URL *(All your webhooks will be signed with [SECRET] so you can verify their integrity.)*